# Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: java, spring

I am just learning how to do component scan without using xml file. But my application worked when I did with xml code but without xml my application is throwing the above error it maybe cliche but I am new to these so hope u can help me out. if I am using component in my xml or without my xml its not working. Here are my codes
this was my complete error

```
Jan 25, 2022 9:38:04 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\Spring\Spring-java-config\bin\com\lepras\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [D:\Spring\Spring-java-config\bin\com\lepras\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\Spring\Spring-java-config\bin\com\lepras\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [D:\Spring\Spring-java-config\bin\com\lepras\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:89)
    at com.lepras.springdemo.JavaConfigAppdemo.main(JavaConfigAppdemo.java:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [D:\Spring\Spring-java-config\bin\com\lepras\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57)
    ... 19 more
```

Coach interface

```
package com.lepras.springdemo;

public interface Coach {
    public String getDailyWorkout();
}
```

TennisCoach.class

```
package com.lepras.springdemo;

public class TennisCoach implements Coach {

    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "practice bakchand volley";
    }

}
```

SportsConfig.class

```
package com.lepras.springdemo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.lepras.springdemo")
public class SportsConfig {

}
```

Main

```
package com.lepras.springdemo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class JavaConfigAppdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context  = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SportsConfig.class);
        Coach theCoach = context.getBean("TennisCoach", Coach.class);
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the actual error-
Unsupported class file major version 61 , are you using class files compiled on a higher jdk?

Comment: I am using java jdk 16.0.2 for both class and java file. But this was built on eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer it was because my eclipse was using jdk 17 to run whereas I had jdk 16.0.2 installed you just have to click the project->build path->configure build path->java compiler->compiler compliance level to a lower jdk
thanks to everyone who helped